# How can I access ESP32-CAM from outside local network other than port forwarding?

Tags: arduino-ide, home-automation, esp32-cam

I have a ESP32-CAM AIThinker which I have programmed using Arduino IDE to stream video.  I have another board ESP8266-12e that I am using on a MQTT system that turns on and off the ESP32 as well as sending it the Name and password of my local network to sign in.  When the ESP32-CAM is on and streaming I can access it on my local network and by port forwarding in my Router I can sign in and view it from anywhere.  I have built a Mac and Android app which will access and stream the ESP32 displaying it inside the app.
I would rather NOT port forward my router.  Is there a way to add some code to the ESP32 so that I could use Apple TV, or the Android equivalent, or HomeKit, to open the port associated with the ESP32 so it can be accessed outside my local network?  Port forward is not real secure and I would like to avoid it if possible.

I have added some code to try to POST the jpg-stream to my WIX website where I added a page with an image.  However even though the website got the POST and it was valid I received a response code 403 FORBIDDEN this is the full response.

```
10:25:03.026 -> 403
10:25:03.026 -> <html>
10:25:03.026 -> <head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
10:25:03.026 -> <body>
10:25:03.026 -> <center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
10:25:03.026 -> <hr><center>nginx</center>
10:25:03.026 -> </body>
10:25:03.026 -> </html>
```

Here is the code currently running on the ESP32-CAM;

```
#include "src/OV2640.h"
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WebServer.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "FS.h"                // SD Card ESP32
#include "SD_MMC.h"            // SD Card ESP32
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <EEPROM.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
//ADDED FOR POST
#include <HTTPClient.h>

int know;
#define CAMERA_MODEL_AI_THINKER
#include "camera_pins.h"
//for reconnect
unsigned long previousMillis = 0;
unsigned long interval = 30000;
//stuff to bring in string
const byte numChars = 100;
char receivedChars[numChars];
char tempChars[numChars];        // temporary array for use when parsing
// variables to hold the parsed data
char messageFromPC[numChars] = {0};
float floatFromPC = 0;
char ssidString[numChars] = {0};
float floatFromPC2 = 0;
char pskString[numChars] = {0};
char IP[numChars] = {0};
char zone[numChars] = {0};
char myChar[numChars]= {0};
char myChar2[numChars]= {0};
char myChar3[numChars]= {0};
char myChar4[numChars]= {0};
boolean newData = false;
//end stuff ti bring in string
String f;
int addr = 0; 
OV2640 cam;

WebServer server(XX);


const char HEADER[] = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n" \
                      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *\r\n" \
                      "Content-Type: multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=123456789000000000000987654321\r\n";
const char BOUNDARY[] = "\r\n--123456789000000000000987654321\r\n";
const char CTNTTYPE[] = "Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\nContent-Length: ";
const int hdrLen = strlen(HEADER);
const int bdrLen = strlen(BOUNDARY);
const int cntLen = strlen(CTNTTYPE);

void handle_jpg_stream(void)
{
  char buf[32];
  int s;

  WiFiClient client = server.client();

  client.write(HEADER, hdrLen);
  client.write(BOUNDARY, bdrLen);

  while (true)
  {
    if (!client.connected()) break;
    cam.run();
    s = cam.getSize();
    client.write(CTNTTYPE, cntLen);
    sprintf( buf, "%d\r\n\r\n", s );
    client.write(buf, strlen(buf));
    client.write((char *)cam.getfb(), s);
    client.write(BOUNDARY, bdrLen);
  }
}

const char JHEADER[] = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n" \
                       "Content-disposition: inline; filename=capture.jpg\r\n" \
                       "Content-type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n";
const int jhdLen = strlen(JHEADER);

void handle_jpg(void)
{
  WiFiClient client = server.client();

  cam.run();
  if (!client.connected()) return;

  client.write(JHEADER, jhdLen);
  client.write((char *)cam.getfb(), cam.getSize());
  
}

void handleNotFound()
{
  String message = "Server is running!\n\n";
  message += "URI: ";
  message += server.uri();
  message += "\nMethod: ";
  message += (server.method() == HTTP_GET) ? "GET" : "POST";
  message += "\nArguments: ";
  message += server.args();
  message += "\n";
  server.send(200, "text / plain", message);
}

void setup()
{

  Serial.begin(57600);
  Serial.print("setup");

delay(10000);

//RESET EEPROM COMMENT OUT
if(Serial.available()){
delay(2000);
  
  recvWithStartEndMarkers();

    if (newData == true) {
        strcpy(tempChars, receivedChars);
            // this temporary copy is necessary to protect the original data
            //   because strtok() used in parseData() replaces the commas with \0
        parseData();
        showParsedData();
        newData = false;
    }
}
//TO HERE
    delay(10000);
    Serial.print("network");
    Serial.print(ssidString);
    Serial.print("pass");
    Serial.print(pskString);
    Serial.print("time zone");
    Serial.print(zone);

    
if(ssidString[0] != '\0'){
 EEPROM.begin(512);  //Initialize EEPROM
 
  // write appropriate byte of the EEPROM.
  // these values will remain there when the board is
  // turned off.
  
 EEPROM.write(addr, 'A');    //Write character A
  addr++;                      //Increment address
  EEPROM.write(addr, 'B');    //Write character B
  addr++;                      //Increment address
  EEPROM.write(addr, 'C');    //Write character C
 
 
  //Write string to eeprom

  //RESET EEPROM SWITCH THESE TWO
 String www =  ssidString +String(",") + String(pskString) + String(",")+String(zone)+String(",");
 //String www =  newString +String(",") + String(oldString) + String(",")+String(zoneString)+String(",");
  Serial.print (www);
  
for(int i=0;i<www.length();i++) //loop upto string lenght www.length() returns length of string
  {
    EEPROM.write(0x0F+i,www[i]); //Write one by one with starting address of 0x0F
  }
  

  EEPROM.commit(); 
  //Read string from eeprom           //Increment address
  //COMMENT OUT NEXT BRACKET RESET EEPROM
}
//RESET EEPROM COMMENT OUT NEXT SECTION
else if(ssidString[0] == '\0'){
   EEPROM.begin(512);
    Serial.println("WHAT"); //Goto next line, as ESP sends some garbage when you reset it  
  Serial.print(char(EEPROM.read(addr)));    //Read from address 0x00
  addr++;                      //Increment address
  Serial.print(char(EEPROM.read(addr)));    //Read from address 0x01
  addr++;                      //Increment address
  Serial.print(char(EEPROM.read(addr)));    //Read from address 0x02
  addr++;   //Increment address
  Serial.print(char(EEPROM.read(addr)));    //Read from address 0x03
 
  

  //Read string from eeprom
  String www;   
  //Here we dont know how many bytes to read it is better practice to use some terminating character
  //Lets do it manually www.circuits4you.com  total length is 20 characters
  for(int i=0;i<100;i++) 
  {
    www = www + char(EEPROM.read(0x0F+i)); //Read one by one with starting address of 0x0F    
  } 
  
 
 Serial.println("this");
  Serial.print(www);  //Print the text on serial monitor
  
  www.toCharArray(myChar,100);
    char * token = strtok(myChar,",");
    char * token2 = strtok(NULL,",");
    char * token3 = strtok(NULL,",");

Serial.println("one");
 Serial.print(token);
 Serial.println("two");
 Serial.print(token2);
 Serial.println("three");
 Serial.print(token3);

  
strcpy(myChar2,token);
strcpy(myChar3,token2);
strcpy(myChar4,token3);

//RESET EEPROM COMMENT OUT TO HERE
}


#define SSID1 ssidString
#define PWD1 pskString
  
  camera_config_t config;
  config.ledc_channel = LEDC_CHANNEL_0;
  config.ledc_timer = LEDC_TIMER_0;
  config.pin_d0 = Y2_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d1 = Y3_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d2 = Y4_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d3 = Y5_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d4 = Y6_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d5 = Y7_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d6 = Y8_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d7 = Y9_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_xclk = XCLK_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_pclk = PCLK_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_vsync = VSYNC_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_href = HREF_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_sscb_sda = SIOD_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_sscb_scl = SIOC_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_pwdn = PWDN_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_reset = RESET_GPIO_NUM;
  config.xclk_freq_hz = 20000000;
  config.pixel_format = PIXFORMAT_JPEG;

  // Frame parameters
  //  config.frame_size = FRAMESIZE_UXGA;
  config.frame_size = FRAMESIZE_VGA;
  config.jpeg_quality = 12;
  config.fb_count = 2;

#if defined(CAMERA_MODEL_ESP_EYE)
  pinMode(13, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(14, INPUT_PULLUP);
#endif

  cam.init(config);

  IPAddress ip;

  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  if(ssidString[0] != '\0'){
   // digitalWrite(33,LOW);
  WiFi.begin(ssidString, pskString);
  Serial.println("zone");
  Serial.print(zone);
 know = atoi(zone);
  }
  else if(ssidString[0] == '\0'){
     WiFi.begin(myChar2, myChar3);
     Serial.println("myChar4");
      know = atoi(myChar4);
     Serial.print(myChar4);
  }
 
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
  {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(F("."));
  }
  String rrr = String("/") + String(zone) + String("/") + String ("1");
  Serial.print("rrr");
  Serial.println(rrr);
  ip = WiFi.localIP();
  Serial.println(F("WiFi connected"));
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println(ip);
  Serial.print("Stream Link: http://");
  Serial.print(ip);
  Serial.println(rrr);//userName
  server.on(String(rrr), HTTP_GET, handle_jpg_stream);
  server.on("/jpg", HTTP_GET, handle_jpg);
  server.onNotFound(handleNotFound);
  server.begin();
  Serial.print("loop");

  

delay(1000);
  

 
}

void loop()
{

 if (WiFi.status() == WL_DISCONNECTED){


  if(ssidString[0] != '\0'){
  
  WiFi.begin(ssidString, pskString);
  Serial.println("zone");
  Serial.print(zone);
 know = atoi(zone);
  }
  else if(ssidString[0] == '\0'){
     WiFi.begin(myChar2, myChar3);
     Serial.println("myChar4");
      know = atoi(myChar4);
     Serial.print(myChar4);
  }
   while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
  {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(F("."));
  }}
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

  if((WiFi.status()!= WL_CONNECTED) & (currentMillis-previousMillis >= interval)){
    Serial.print(millis());
    WiFi.disconnect();
    WiFi.reconnect();
    previousMillis = currentMillis;
  }
 else if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED){
```

//THIS IS THE CODE I ADDED TRYING TO POST VIDEO

```
HTTPClient http;
  http.begin ("https://www.creatucate.com/video-1");
  http.addHeader("Content-Type","image/jpeg");

  int httpResponseCode = http.POST("POSTING from ESP32");

  if(httpResponseCode>0){
    String response = http.getString();
    Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
    Serial.println(response);
  }
  else{
    Serial.print("Error on sending POST: ");
    Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
  }
```

//END NEW CODE

```
server.handleClient();
 
}}
    //more new stuff for string
    void recvWithStartEndMarkers() {
        static boolean recvInProgress = false;
        static byte ndx = 0;
        char startMarker = '<';
        char endMarker = '>';
        char rc;
    
    
        while (Serial.available() > 0 && newData == false) {
            rc = Serial.read();
    
            if (recvInProgress == true) {
                if (rc != endMarker) {
                    receivedChars[ndx] = rc;
                    ndx++;
                    if (ndx >= numChars) {
                        ndx = numChars - 1;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    receivedChars[ndx] = '\0'; // terminate the string
                    recvInProgress = false;
                    ndx = 0;
                    newData = true;
                }
            }
    
            else if (rc == startMarker) {
                recvInProgress = true;
            }
        }
    }
    
    //============
    //RESET EEPROM COMMENT OUT ALL THE REST
    void parseData() {      // split the data into its parts
    
        char * strtokIndx; // this is used by strtok() as an index
    
        strtokIndx = strtok(tempChars,",");      // get the first part - the string
        strcpy(messageFromPC, strtokIndx); // copy it to messageFromPC
     
        strtokIndx = strtok(NULL, ","); // this continues where the previous call left off
        strcpy(ssidString,strtokIndx);
        
    
        strtokIndx = strtok(NULL, ",");
        strcpy(pskString,strtokIndx);
        strtokIndx = strtok(NULL, ",");
        strcpy(zone,strtokIndx);
       
    
    }
    
    //============
    
    void showParsedData() {
        Serial.print("Message ");
        Serial.println(messageFromPC);
        Serial.print("water level ");
        Serial.println(floatFromPC);
        Serial.println(ssidString);
        Serial.print("battery level ");
        Serial.println(floatFromPC2);
        Serial.println(pskString);
        Serial.print("time zone is ");
       Serial.println(zone);
      
      
    }
```

If this is not the correct place for this question please advise me.  I am not even sure this can be done but I hope so.

Comment: you can push the frame data to a web-based WebSocket server, which you can connect to your app w/o port configs. You could also do that with a web-based http server for that matter; POST the image to the server, GET it from the app.

Comment: I have changed my original post to include code to POST to a http server and the response from the server.  The request contained valid data and was understood by the server, but the server is refusing action.  I am trying to post to WIX.  Could you give me some more guidance?